# R-module homomorphism diagram with exact rows

Tags: diagrams, commutative-diagrams

I'd like to draw the following R-module homomorphism diagram). I tried to use the Ti*k*Z package, but got somehow complicated with LuaTeX and I don't have any idea how to use that. Is there a simple way to graph it? (I use TeXShop).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Have you tried something?

Comment: I tried using graphs from the tikz package, but then the compiler complained about something with luatex...

Comment: You can try or with `tikz-cd` or with `xy` package or `amscd`. Can you post your complete code, please?

Comment: No no...for the green check mark...wait a bit of time...Probably there is another better answer than mine. Please, can you delete the check mark?

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway! PS. Do you how to center the diagramm in the document?

Answer (score 1):

I have used an old package named `xy`...with the same tips of `tikz-cd` package (you see the `cmtip` option).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
0 \ar[r] & A \ar[r]^{f} \ar[d]^{\theta} & B \ar[r]^{g} \ar[d]^{\phi} & C \ar[r] \ar[d]^{\psi}& 0 \\
0 \ar[r] & A' \ar[r]^{f'} & B' \ar[r]^{g'} & C' \ar[r] & 0. 
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** See the request of the user below your question.

You can use `\[...\]` to have an enviroment in math-mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum{2}
\[\xymatrix{
0 \ar[r] & A \ar[r]^{f} \ar[d]^{\theta} & B \ar[r]^{g} \ar[d]^{\phi} & C \ar[r] \ar[d]^{\psi}& 0 \\
0 \ar[r] & A' \ar[r]^{f'} & B' \ar[r]^{g'} & C' \ar[r] & 0. 
} \]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A `tikz-cd` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2em, column sep=2em]
%
0\rar & A \dar["\theta"] \rar["f"] & B \dar["\phi"] \rar["g"]& C \dar["\psi"] \rar & 0 \\
0\rar & A’ \rar["f’"]& B’ \rar["g’"]& C’ \rar & 0
%
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]